# Comparing columns in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

Sorry in advance for inappropriate question.I am a beginner in php and laravel. Wondering where i am doing mistake in the following code fragment.

```
$customer_vlan = Customer::select('vlan_id')->get();
$vlans = Vlans::where(function($query) use ($customer_vlan){
$query->where('id','!=',$customer_vlan);
})->get();
```

I have two tables in database."Customer" table has a column 'vlan_id'. In first query i am trying to fetch used vlan_id.

For second table "Vlans", column'id' holds all possible vlan. So i am trying to find which vlan's not used.

Comment: Is there an error? What is happening?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or exact error message, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.. Read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the help documentation, and [What Questions Can I Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  Remember, you also need to include [MVE: Minimal, complete, verifiable examples:] (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to compare id with a collection. Then the result is all of the `Vlans`.

```
$query->where('id','!=',$customer_vlan);
```

I think the best way to do this is loop through `$customer_vlan` collection and push `$customer_vlan[$i]->id` to an array. Then you can use this:

```
$query->whereNotIn('id', $arrayOfId);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.Much appreciated.

Comment: If this answer is what you want, please accept it as the answer of your question, thanks xD.